# Google Apps Script Variable Reassignment

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I'm trying to build a staff schedule for a year, where different days of the week require different amounts of staff. I want to output the roster into a Google Spreadsheet

My approach is to have an array with all staff names, and then for each day of the year blank out x names from the staff array. X is equal to staff.length - how many people needed today.

I've written the code and my output is not what I expected. The first day looks correct, but every subsequent day returns an empty array.

var **staff** is initialised & assigned on LoC3. But on LoC12 when I have the log output what's in **staff** I see an empty array. I can see that assigning an empty array to **rosterToday** is how the resulting **rosterFull** is empty, but I don't understand what is setting **staff** to [, , , , , , ]

Furthermore if I blank out LoC17 (rosterToday[i] = ""), the phantom reassignment of **staff** seems to disappear.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
function RosterTest()
{
  var staff = ["Adam", "Bob", "Chris", "Dave", "Ed", "Fred", "Garry"];
  var dailyRequirement = [0, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 2]; // num staff needed today
  var rosterFull = []; // push each day's roster in here
  var period = 7; // test with only 7 days, then ramp up to 365

  for (var d=0; d<period; d++)
  {
    var rosterToday = staff; // initially start with the full roster
    var reduce = staff.length - dailyRequirement[d];
    Logger.log("d="+d+" staff="+staff);
    // when d>=1 staff becomes [, , , , , , ]

    for (var i=0; i<reduce; i++)
    {
      rosterToday[i] = "";
    }
    rosterFull.push(rosterToday);
  }
  for (var i=0; i<rosterFull.length; i++)
  {Logger.log(rosterFull[i]);} // shows an arr of len 7 with empty arrs

  // spreadsheet.getRange(row, col, height, width).setValues(rosterWeek);
}
```

I know this will always have preference for the first few staff in the staff array, but I already have code to shuffle them. This is just a few isolated lines.

Comment: Array.slice() is your friend here.

Comment: I could, but I want those elements to remain as blanks in the inner/today array so when I call setValues() the actual staff members are still in alignment in the columns.

Comment: The way you are approaching it the staff roster is always picking from the 'left' of the staff list - is this what you want? Adam is always picked and Garry 3 times only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without getting into whether what you are asking is what you actually want to do the reason why `staff` is empty after the first run because of the line

```
rosterToday = staff;
```

this assigns staff as a reference to rosterToday - so all the `rosterToday[i]` does is also applied to `staff`. you need to make rosterToday a copy.

```
rosterToday = staff.slice(); //makes a shallow copy of the array
```

this will solve that specific problem.

beyond that you can replicate what you have there also using `Array.slice()`

```
var rosterToday = [];
var rosterLength = staff.length;

for (var d = 0; d < dailyRequirement.length; d += 1) {

  rosterDay = staff
                .slice(0,dailyRequirement[d]-1)
                .concat(Array(rosterLength - d));
  rosterFull.push(rosterDay)

}
```

But I'm not convinced this is what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon. I had no idea JS switches to passing by reference for object/arr assignment, as opposed to pass by value for primitives.

Yep, I'm also aware that Adam is taking a lot more work than Garry, but I've got code further down that records the last guy to be assigned each day and then assigns the next person first on tomorrow's roster.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the staff array seems empty, but I think it could be an effect of trying to assign a two dimensional dataset to a one dimensional array. You want the variable rosterFull to contain the required names for each day. That would mean you need an array with 7 X the-amount-of-needed-staff-per-day dimensions.

```
function RosterTest()
{
   var staff = ["Adam", "Bob", "Chris", "Dave", "Ed", "Fred", "Garry"];
   var dailyRequirement = [0, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 2]; // num staff needed today
   var period = 7; // test with only 7 days, then ramp up to 365
   var rosterFull = new Array(7); // create an array with 7 rows that represent the 7 days of the week

  for (var d=0; d<period; d++)
  {

    var rosterToday = [];

    for(var i=0; i<dailyRequirement[d]; i++){
      rosterToday[i] = staff[i];
    }

    rosterFull[d] = rosterToday; //assign the array with the required staff to the corresponding day.

  }

}
```

I don't understand the variable reduce. That would give you the amount of persons that are not needed today, while I suppose you want the amount of persons that are needed.

Comment: I'm looking at this in reverse. Assigning everyone to rosterToday, and then assigning blanks for persons not needed today, this is to preserve the length of all of these 'inner' arrays being pushed into rosterFull. By preserving the same length I can call setValues(rosterFull) and have the result in a Google Spreadsheet